# Flex, a mx:Tree component in Spark application, the scrollbar auto send to top when collapsed a tree node

Tags: apache-flex, tree, scrollbar, flex-spark

Flex, a mx:Tree in Spark application, the scrollbar will move to top when i collapsed a tree node, the test code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" 
               creationComplete="init()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;

        [Bindable]
        private var treeData:XML =
            <node label='root'>
                <node label="Monkeys">
                    <node label="South America">
                        <node label="Coastal"/>
                        <node label="Inland"/>
                    </node>
                    <node label="Africa" isBranch="true">
                        <node label="Coastal"/>
                        <node label="Inland"/>
                    </node>
                    <node label="Asia" isBranch="true">
                        <node label="Coastal"/>
                        <node label="Inland"/>
                    </node>
                </node>
                <node label="Sharks">
                    <node label="South America" isBranch="true">
                        <node label="Coastal"/>
                        <node label="Inland"/>
                    </node>
                    <node label="Africa" isBranch="true">
                        <node label="Coastal"/>
                        <node label="Inland"/>
                    </node>
                    <node label="Asia" >
                        <node label="Coastal"/>
                        <node label="Inland"/>
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>;

        private function init():void{
            myTree.expandChildrenOf(myTree.firstVisibleItem, true);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
    <mx:Tree id="myTree" 
             y="50" 
             width="221" 
             height="207" 
             horizontalCenter="0"
             dataProvider="{treeData.node}"
             labelField="@label"/> 
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of amazing issues with MX Tree e.g. try horizontal tree scrolling when item icons are shown.

I suggest you to consider migrating to an open-source custom component called [Spark Tree](http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/spark-tree).

Comment: I am strongly suggest the same answer Maxim Kachurovskiy post. I had really serious issue with "mx Tree", and seems like Adobe is goin for Spark version in Flex 5.0, untill then - Maxim's tree is the panacea.

Comment: thank you very much, I defined a custom tree class extends mx:Tree, but it's full of small mistakes, maybe I need to extend it from List class like "Spark Tree"